# Cross Platform Virtual Currency iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm designing a multi-platform online game, where certain elements can be accessed on a phone or a desktop. My planned model is In App purchases with Virtual Currency. From what I read though, it appears any In App Purchase must remain exclusive to that device. That would be problematic for a currency, as it would mean the User has some of his money on his device that is inaccessible from the desktop or other platforms. This would be unacceptable.

To get around this can you sell an item that is WORTH a set value in your in game store, so that only that item is tied to the device but your currency can be shared freely then? (Such as selling Gold Bars as an in-app purchase, that the player can sell in the in game store for in game currency)

Comment: The purchase doesn't have to remain exclusive to the device. You can create an "account" for the user in your server and update their balance there. Their balance would then be available anywhere they log in with the same account details

Comment: To elaborate a little on what @Paulw11 said, once your in-app purchase (assumed to be "consumable") completes, the in-app purchase itself would be that device only, and it would be up to you to make that in-game _value_ (the amount of virtual currency purchased, for example) accessible elsewhere through the use of your server tracking. You would not/could not use Apple's purchase tracking to have that propagated to other game locations.

Comment: OK I see, I was under the impression it would mean, that I couldn't share the currency across platforms (at least the amount they bought for that platform). I understand the concept of having a server ect (my game is online after all), I was merely viewing this from a rule perspective and not an implementation one. I thought the purchase itself would have to stay ON the device and I wouldn't be allowed to propagate it across platforms with a server.

Comment: Are you guys sure is it possible?
AppStore guidelines are quite clear about it:

`11.1
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
11.2
Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected`

Comment: Yeah, that is sort of my concern. Maybe the key words 'additional features and functionality' wouldn't apply to something like a virtual currency though, as that it's really just a consumable item that you can already get in the game through other means anyways.

Comment: @AwDogsGo2Heaven Did you find a solution? What approach you took?